# Core Data Performance issue in device

Tags: iphone, performance, core-data, ios-simulator, device

My application needs to use web service and get some data in json.
I need to parse the json and feed the data in my persistance store, everything was working superb until i tested my application in actual device, the application looked like it was holding it until I got frustrated and then at last it pooped on my face x-(

here i have a method for insertOrReplaceObjectForEntityForName

```
+(id) insertOrReplaceObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:_context WithPredicateString:(NSString *)predicateString, ...{

    NSManagedObject *object;

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, predicateString);

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString arguments:ap];
    [req setPredicate:pred];

    int count = [_context countForFetchRequest:req error:nil];

    if(count > 0){
        NSArray *arr = [_context executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
        object = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else{
        object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    }

    va_end(ap);

    return object;
}
```

Here the simple operation of one line is taking around .004 secs and in parsing the data I have to do this operation around 1000 times combined with many other operations, that makes my parsing too much heavy process. I already have many drugs in my default db and i have to check if the drug exist and if it exists i have to edit its values.

```
Drug *drug = [NSEntityDescription insertOrReplaceObjectForEntityForName:@"Drug" inManagedObjectContext:parsingContext WithPredicateString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"drugId == '%@'",[drugDetails objectForKey:@"DrugId"]]];
```

I was using core data to keep the history maintained in the application, but now i think i would need to move away from core data and forget about keeping the history, unless someone here can help me.
I have already spent a lot of time in making my application and now client is hitting my legs, any suggestions??

Comment: 1000 is a lot for core data.  Try skipping the count.  if `[_context executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];` returns 0 objects, you don't need the count operation.  The other operation is to bundle 20 drugIDs at a  time to reduce the number of fetches.  Lastly, make sure ALL of this is happening on a background queue.

Comment: I have taken care of background queue etc.. but the problem is that the fetch is taking a lot of time and it is reducing the performance by many folds.

Comment: Do you think that fetching all the records at once and using filteredArrayUsingPredicate method will be faster?

Comment: Almost certainly.  w/ 1000 records though, just be careful of memory usage.  Maybe do it in small batches (like 50 or 100 at a time) depending on how memory intensive your usage is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yogesh,

The delays you are seeing are not particularly from Core Data but from the slow speed of flash on an iOS device. How do you mitigate this?

Flash reads very large blocks (128kB I'm told) and then has to throw them away in DB scatter-gather operations. Hence, you want to get as much data as possible from each fetch.

Your code does a fetch per item in the json. If you used the low level tools of Instruments, as I have on my apps, you will most likely see that your app is mostly idle waiting on the flash.

You build aggregate fetches with the `in` predicate operator. IOW, go collect all of your `drugID`s into a set or array. BTW, depending on your json, this can frequently be done with a single line of code using `-valueForKey:`. As in this predicate format :

```
@"drugId in'%@'", [drugDetails valueForKey:@"DrugId"]
```

where `drugDetails` is an array of objects. This search lets the DB aggregate all of its page fetches. It then returns you an array of the records which already exist. You can then easily use set operations to chose to update or create records as you wish. Then you can flush them out to flash in a single `-save:`.

Andrew

Comment: Thank you Adonoho, it was really helpful. By the way what is the meaning of IOW and BTW?

Comment: Yogesh, IOW == In Other Words; BTW == By The Way. BTW, there are some unneeded characters in the predicate format: `@"drugId in %@", [drugDetails valueForKey:@"DrugId"]`. Also, if you judge my answer as the most useful to you, then please check the checkmark by the up/down arrows. Andrew

Comment: I dont have that right, not enough point to rate you up, if you give +1 to my qn then probably i would be able to vote you